# Apollo client cache - Network error: Cannot read property ‘appStateOfUI’ of undefined at resolver

Tags: graphql-js, react-apollo, apollo-client

The code is like this. I was following `apollo-link-state` example.

```
const defaultState = {
    "appStateOfUI": {
        __typename: "appStateOfUI",
        first: "John",
        last: "Doe"
    }
};
```

we warm up the client with these defaults like this:

```
const stateLink = withClientState({
    cache,
    defaults: defaultState,
    resolvers: {
        Mutation: {
            updateAppState: ...
        }
    }
});
```

And initialized my client like this.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([
        stateLink,
        new HttpLink({...})
    ]),
    cache
});
```

Everything is normal. But couldn't understand why mine was not working.

After spending quite some time, I found that some utilities are broken from the library end, and people suggested roll back. In other [thread](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link-state/issues/188) a hack/fix. Just wanted to share it here so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FIX`: Modify your defaults like this appStateOfUI`@client` - by including client with in the property. It should look like this:

```
const defaultState = {
    "appStateOfUI@client": {
        __typename: "appStateOfUI",
        first: "John",
        last: "Doe"
    }
};
```

and the rest is same..